# How to write the regex for these logs?

Tags: regex

I need help in writing regex for the below logs.

```
text1,-,text2,"So on"
```

```
text1," This is a comma , in between the double inverted commas",text2,"So on"
```

I want to capture the all the values separated by commas.

Regex for 1st one which I have written is :

```
(\S+),([^,]*),(\S+),"(.*?)"
```

Regex for 2nd one is :

```
(\S+),"(.*?)",(\S+),"(.*?)"
```

I want a single regex which can match both of these logs.

Please help.

Regards,

Mitesh Agrawal

Comment: It looks like a CSV, can you use a CSV parser? What is the programming language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your reply and hope you are doing well. I am writing this parser for SIEM tool called ArcSight which is based on Ruby based regex. Request you to help me with the regex for this patterns to match with a single regex.

Comment: In Onigmo (Ruby regex library), you may use named groups, and repeat them throughout the pattern, `(?<one>\S+),(?<two>[^,]*),(?<three>\S+),"(?<four>.*?)"|(?<one>\S+),"(?<two>.*?)",(?<three>\S+),"(?<four>.*?)"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DKxPPq/1)